# Are unit tests supposed to be implementation independent?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I've always been told that unit tests are supposed to be implementation independent. This makes perfect sense to me - if the implementation of a function changes, it should still meet its API contract and thus the unit tests shouldn't need to be changed.

However, this seems to conflict with the idea of mocking. If I need to mock external dependencies, this immediately makes my tests dependent on my implementation. If I were to use different dependencies, I'd have to change the mock code in my unit tests. Is it impractical/unreasonable to make all unit tests entirely implementation independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I try my best.

Let say you write unit test for class `PrepaidPointManager`. It has method `void Recharge(int points)` which recharge users point account. During implementation of this class you decided that it should depends on some `ICreditCardProvider` (because you want to exchange cash for points) and also depends on `IPointRepository` because you want to persist new points balance in some storage.

Recharge method make some calculation before using credit card provider and before storing balance.

1. When you write unit test for this class (which is your concrete implementation) you don't want to drag to your test any specific implementation of `CreditCardProvider`(maybe because it will require internet connection and is slow). The same story is with `PointRepository`.

For these dependencies you create stubs/mocks (`ICreditCardProvider` and `IPointRepository`) and next inject them to `PrepaidPointManager`.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldCallCreditCardProviderPoints() {
   // arrange
   ICreditCardProvider creditCardProvideMock = mock<ICreditCardProvider>();
   IPointRepository pointRepositoryStub = stub<IPointRepository>();
   PrepaidPointManager sut = new PrepaidPointManager(creditCardProvideMock ,pointRepositoryStub );

   // act
   sut.Recharge(100);

   // asserts/verify
   creditCardProvideMock.Received().Charge(/*...*.) // verify if charge was called
}
```

Right now your test is **independent** from implementation details of dependencies(ICreditCardProvider, IPointRepository). That is how I understand term *implementation independent* from your question.

Of course if you decide that PrepaidPointManager should have other dependencies then unit test code also need to change.

In well designed system you write code against abstraction and when you really need to change dependencies of some class then this change will affect only small amount of tests.

Main idea behind mocking (from me perspective ) is when you write test case you say something like this:

- I don't care how credit card provider works
- I don't care how persistence work

I just want to test if when I recharge points then credit card provider is used.

If you want test implementation of concrete CreditCardProvider then simply create new set of test for this purpose.

### Conclusion:

Using mock is in fact really practical. If you like you can learn few things from this book [Art of unit testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)